# Path to Firebase Admin Key in Java servlet

Tags: java, android, servlets, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I keep getting a

> FileNotFoundException

when trying to initialize my app with *Firebase* saying *it cannot find my adminsdk.json service key*.

This is a specific error as I am trying to initialize Firebase in an *Android Module Servlet*.

Here is what my module project structure looks like:

[image]

And here is the code in my Serlvet that is trying to intialize `FirebaseOptions`:

```
FirebaseOptions options = null;
        try {
            options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                    .setServiceAccount(new FileInputStream("leadsbackend\\src\\main\\webapp\\tt-social-firebase-adminsdk.json"))
                    .setDatabaseUrl(FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL)
                    .build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And here is the error in the console:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: TTLeads\leadsbackend\src\main\webapp\tt-social-firebase-adminsdk.json (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at com.nicholas.leadsbackend.LeadsServlet.sendToFirebase(LeadsServlet.java:63)
    at com.nicholas.leadsbackend.LeadsServlet.sendToBase(LeadsServlet.java:57)
    at com.nicholas.leadsbackend.LeadsServlet.doGet(LeadsServlet.java:37)
```

I am pretty sure I am not setting the URI correctly, but how would someone be able to reference a file in your package structure correctly? Any help is very appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I had cracked my head to enable reading of JSON key file in the system, when I stumbled on this article at: [How to Use Facebook Account Kit to Authenticate Firebase App Users on Android](http://atimothee.xyz/blog/2016/09/17/how-to-use-facebook-account-kit-to-authenticate-firebase-app-users-on-android/http://atimothee.xyz/blog/2016/09/17/how-to-use-facebook-account-kit-to-authenticate-firebase-app-users-on-android/). In this article, it explains in details to how to setup Firebase Admin SDK in a Cloud Endpoints module. I will summarize the steps here:

1. Place your *serviceAccountKey.json* in your apps' WEB-INF folder.
2. Insert this in your appengineweb.xml:

   ```
   <resource-files>
       <include path="/**.json" />
   </resource-files>
   ```
3. Define a class somewhere like the one below. Have a seperate init() method compulsorily:

   ```
   public class FirebaseService {

   public static void init() {
       try {
           FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream(new File("WEB-INF/serviceAccountKey.json"));
           FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
               .setCredential(FirebaseCredentials.fromCertificate(serviceAccount))
               .setDatabaseUrl("https://[YOUR_APP_NAME].firebaseio.com/")
               .build();
           FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
           System.out.print("In Firebase Init module...!!");
       } catch(FileNotFoundException ignored) {}
   }
   ```
4. Invoke this method in any of the **static{}** code in any of the Endpoints defined by you. For example:

   ```
   static {
       ObjectifyService.register(FCMTokenMap.class);
       FirebaseService.init();
   }
   ```

   5. You can invoke other Firebase methods which involve Database, FCM, etc from anywhere..!

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue like so:

I needed to place the .json file in my WEB-INF folder, and then user `ServletContext` to grab the resource as a stream, here is my example:

```
        FirebaseOptions options = null;
        ServletContext ctx = getServletContext();
        InputStream in = ctx.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/tt-social-firebase-adminsdk.json");
        try {
            options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                    .setServiceAccount(in)
                    .setDatabaseUrl(FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL)
                    .build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

That resolved all issues I was having accessing the file. Hope this helps someone else.