# How to specify a Java file path for both Mac and Ubuntu

Tags: java, macos, ubuntu

I'm using IntelliJ and Spring and Java to locally develop an app on a Mac, and then deploy to a tomcat server on AWS, using Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-1048-aws x86_64).
I'm having trouble specifying the file path so that it works in both environments.

My code is

```
        InputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/static/web/data/ReportDates.json");
        JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(fileStream);
        JsonObject reportDates = reader.readObject();
        reader.close();
```

When I run locally, the file is read in correctly. It is located in:

```
src/main/resources/static/web/data/ReportDates.json
```

But when I deploy, that code results in the error message:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: src/main/resources/static/web/data/ReportDates.json (No such file or directory)

The actual location of the file on that machine turns out to be:

```
/opt/tomcat/webapps/automentor/WEB-INF/classes/static/web/data/ReportDates.json
```

How can I specify the file path so that it works correctly in both environments?

Comment: Try to use relative path like "/static/web/data/ReportDates.json" or use "classpath:<relative_pathtofile>"

Comment: I have run into this issue specifically for Java Google AppEngine projects and have asked a very similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41253548/path-to-firebase-admin-key-in-java-servlet. Really I had to keep it in the WEB-INF folder and reference that. I hope this can be of help!

Comment: Also, how do you execute it locally? Do you actually deploy it to your local tomcat?

Comment: You never reference `src` from your code

Comment: @MadProgrammer Look after the doublequote in the first line of the code. Is that the reason for the downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have given up on using a single path. @Nicholas Pesa got me thinking -- since I use IDEA, I don't have a fixed WEB-INF folder, so it's easier for me to change the path that should be used than to move the file to a fixed location.
My code now uses:

```
        String filepath = (new File("src/main/resources/static/web/data/ReportDates.json").exists()) ? "src/main/resources/static/web/data/ReportDates.json" : "/opt/tomcat/webapps/automentor/WEB-INF/classes/static/web/data/ReportDates.json";
```